use a component in createApp, passed as prop in a Vue.js
Good day
I am working in a Vue.js app, so I am working with Bootstrap Popover but i need to render content dynamicly, so, I

Create a PopoverComponent logic
Create the component that renders the information inside the popover component I already created

if I import the component inside the PopoverComponentworks ok, but, as I am using the component in several places, I want to create the PopoverGeneric component so I can pass the info i need, as props, and get everything working nice
Of course I can create the a variable in data, import the component in the parent component, as say that the new variable created in data is equal to the imported component and then pass that component to the prop componentName but I would like to know why I can not pass a component as prop without working araound:
<template>
  <div
    :class="popoverClassName"
    class="cursor-pointer"
    :ref="popoverRefName"
    :data-bs-placement="popoverPlace"
    data-bs-toggle="toggle"
    :data-bs-trigger="triggerAction"
  >
    <slot name="triggerElement"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { Popover } from "bootstrap";

export default {
  props: {
    popoverClassName: { type: String, required: true },
    popoverRefName: { type: String, required: true },
    popoverPlace: { type: String, required: true },
    triggerAction: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validator: (value) => ["click", "hover"].includes(value),
    },
    componentName: { type: Object, required: true },
    componentProps: { type: Object, default: () => ({}) },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      popoverInstance: null,
      popoverApp: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createPopover();
  },
  methods: {
    createPopover() {
      const popover = this.$refs[this.popoverRefName];
      const container = document.createElement("div");

      this.popoverApp = createApp(this.componentName, {
        ...this.componentProps,
      });
      this.popoverApp.mount(container);

      this.popoverInstance = new Popover(popover, {
        content: container,
        html: true,
      });
    },
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    if (this.popoverInstance) {
      this.popoverInstance.dispose();
    }
    if (this.popoverApp) {
      this.popoverApp.unmount();
    }
  },
};
</script>


as I mentioned earlier if i do this passing the props in a parent component:
...
    :componentProps="{ name: 'Jhonny' }"
    :componentName="componentVariable"

<script>
import MyNewComponent from './.'

data(){
  return {
   componentVariable: MyNewComponent
  }
}


like that it works, but, I would like to know why is not working without create a variable and assigning the component to it
what is not working is this:
...
    :componentProps="{ name: 'Jhonny' }"
    :componentName="MyNewComponent"

<script>
import MyNewComponent from './.'


EDIT: if you assign the component to a variable you receive a warning that a component is reactive and that can lead to performance issues, so you need to:
import { shallowRef } from 'vue'

<script>
import MyNewComponent from './.'

data(){
  return {
   componentVariable: shallowRef(MyNewComponent)
  }
}



Please, clarify, what exactly code that works and code that doesn't look like. I.e. 2 snippets with possible hints which lines differ. It's not clear from what you posted
